# Ignore invalid url parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to handle invalid URL parameters.

Basically, if the user enters the address as "mydomain.com/nonexistentpath" or anything else after "mydomain.com/" that is invalid (currently I check for one parameter) I want it to be ignored and url set to default "mydomain.com"

Any ideas how to do that and where to put validator?
I'm working on ASP.NET MVC5 website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your web.config. You can either redirect to an Error page or your home page.
`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Index" />`

And also check this answer: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/5507125#5507125)